# Python static class or functions in modules

Tags: python, function, class, organization

I need something to organize some utilty functions.
**Variant 1.**
create module and write all functions in this module.
**Variant 2.**
(since python has no staticclass)
create class with only static methods in main module

In general, there is no big difference.Like :

**var 1)**

```
import functionsmodule
workers = functionmodule.get_all_workers(**kwargs)
```

**var 2)**

```
workers = FunctionClass.get_all_workers(**kwargs)
```

I like the second one though.
Questions is : what is best way to do such organization ?

Comment: Any reason _why_ you like the second one?

Comment: There is **no** best way to do such organization, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Generally speaking however, the first approach is more suitable for scattered functions with little inter-connectivity, whereas a **class** is reserved for cases where the methods are inter-connected and use each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
from functionsmodule import get_all_workers, some_other_method

workers = get_all_workers(**kwargs)
```

After a couple of months learning python, this is *my preferred solution*. It cleans up the code without the need to reference a class or module. I'd only recommend this if your utilities method names WONT clash with builtins or other functions

I'd usually organise these re-usable/utilities within a common package and implement something like:

```
from common.functions import get_all_workers, some_other_method

workers = get_all_workers(**kwargs)
```

EDIT: Based on your "`get_all_workers`" method name - I'd imagine this should go into some sort of persistence/worker class rather than a general utilities class